# Convert Binary String to Unsigned int in Flex3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I am using Flex builder with sdk 3.5. I want to convert binary string to unsigned int. How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second parameter of `parseInt` is the radix.

```
var n:int = parseInt("1010", 2);
trace(n);
```